# How do I terminate a worker thread when the owning object is collected?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have an object that has a `BackgroundWorker` thread (purely a queue of Action delegates). i.e., it's the common, simple single-producer single-consumer scenario.

When the single producer is collected, I would like it to enqueue a Terminate action to the `BackgroundWorker` thread.

It almost sounds easy - use a finalizer - but that breaks the "don't touch a managed resource in a finalizer" rule.

So how do I ensure the thread terminates cleanly once it has no more work to do?

Answers I'd rather not take:

- `IDisposable`: This would require a massive breaking change to the base class, but I accept it is perhaps required (this always seems to be a problem with the IDisposable pattern..)
- `ThreadPool`: These are long running actions that must be run **in order**. So I would consider a dedicated thread to be the logical choice.
- `WeakReference`: I just thought of this one. Perhaps it is the correct way to do this (?). Basically the Thread keeps a `WeakReference` back to the owning object, and periodically wakes itself to check if that `WeakReference` is still alive, when it dies it enqueues a Terminate. Not exactly elegant - I don't like the "periodically wakes itself" bit - but is this the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDisposable` or something similar sounds like the best approach to me - explicitly say when you've finished producing, rather than triggering that from garbage collection.

Fundamentally it sounds like the problem isn't terminating the worker thread - it's indicating that you've finished producing. I do understand that that can be tricky in some situations, but if at *all* possible it'll make your life more predictable if you can do that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I suppose this is the best approach. Just annoying what a breaking change implementing `IDisposable` is (particularly all owners of the object need to start implementing it..) - but I suppose it really is the only way that will shut down the background thread deterministically. Sigh.. I have a lot of work ahead of me.

Comment: @Mania: You have my sympathies. It may be worth thinking about whether reorganizing anything else would make this simpler to approach. Do you have any other sort of event which is fired when you need to shut down the producer?

Comment: Not really. Various methods of the producer add to the background thread's queue (updating values some time later), so once the main code discards of the producer the background thread no longer has a purpose of being. So logically - this producer should implement IDisposable. The problem is that the base class and it's other implementations don't have this same need for a background thread, and so it never occurred to me to implement IDisposable. But I agree, it's a change worth doing. Regards.